How to apply the scrolling bar display instead of the text going to the next line
When I write a really large expression in latex, it usually comes in the next line. Like this,
$$\alpha\beta=(\frac ab+\frac cd)(\frac bc +\frac da)=\frac ac+\frac bd+\frac db+\frac ca=8
$$
But sometimes out of the blue, instead of going to the next line, it remains in a single line and a bar appears...like we can scroll from right to left and view the full expression.
It happens rarely and unexpectedly like a radioactive deacy...I have no idea when it will happen and when it won't.
In my opinion, tha bar display is better than the next line display. What can I do so that I always see the scroll thing instead of the text moving to another line$?$

Usual view:

Rare view:


The rest of the expression can be seen after scrolling.

The formula you typed currently displays in a single line in my display; does it appear in multiple lines in yours? I believe it depends on your interface, and how it interprets mathjax output. The site uses responsive design, so not everyone sees the same thing. I only see scroll bars on some displays. I doubt you can code for them.

What Arturo said. It has happened to me many times in the past that a longish formula is first dispayed with a scrolling bar (may be that is in a preview pane??), but when I reload the page, then it fits.

@it fits?? In a single line or in the next line too?? I am attaching some images to make it more clear

I think we understand what you are talking about (so the images are not really necessary... especially that big...) The point is that what you are seeing is not necessarily what everyone sees, because what you see depends on how your display interacts with the site (which uses responsive design). Your post begins by saying long formulas generally wrap to the next line, "Like this" and a formula follows.... and that formula does not wrap in my display at all. It fits in a single line, no wrapping, no scroll bar. I am fairly sure that I only see scrollbars in some devices.

@ArturoMagidin ohh I understand it now...I'm rn on a phone btw so the display length is not so big ....but I get what you're saying...thnx a lot
